# ¿Como puedo guardar en base de datos múltiples registros a partir de un formulario?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy aprendiendo php y tengo idea de hacer un formulario en el que dinámicamente con JavaScript se puedan añadir nuevas filas , cada una de ellas sería una nueva fila en una base de datos MySQL:

```
<form  method="POST" action="index.php">
    <!-- Fila 1 -->
    <input type="hidden" name="nombreTabla" value="Colegios">
    <input type="text" name="alumnoID">
    <input type="text" name="fechaNacimiento">

    <!-- Fila 2 -->
    <input type="hidden" name="nombreTabla2" value="Colegios">
    <input type="text" name="alumnoID2">
    <input type="text" name="fechaNacimiento2">

    <!-- Una fila mas cada vez que se pulse el boton -->
    <input type="button" value="Añadir otro registro">

    <button type="submit"> Enviar </button>
</form>
```

La variable $_POST[] recibida en el servidor será un array asociativo con $key del nombre de cada input y su valor. Pero a partir de aqui me pierdo.

¿Como podria construir una consulta sql dinamicamente con php que inserte todos los registros?

Comment: Creo que deberias intentarlo primero y despues regresar si tienes dudas especificas.

Comment: Tengo una unica duda y es especifica que es como crear un Insert de multiples registros a partir de un array asociativo @alanfcm

Comment: apoyo la idea de @alanfcm. Primero intentalo y lo que resulte entonces vienes y posteas la problematica resultante.

Comment: Te recomiendo vivamente que uses PDO para esto. Sería cuestión de crear una consulta preparada luego pasar cada dato como parámetro. También sería aconsejable implementar transacciones. Empieza [con este código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2098689/5587982) o bien [con este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653119/5587982) y plantea tu duda, si surge alguna. Este sería el camino idóneo para hacer lo que quieres. Lamento no tener tiempo para dar una respuesta ahora. Es el tipo de pregunta del que quisiera que haya una buena respuesta escrita en castellano.

Comment: [Aquí tienes otro ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232188/5587982) que parece más simple. [Y también aquí, otro ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060755/5587982). Convendría, para que el código quede optimizado, invocar el `execute` fuera del bucle, para insertar los datos en una sola llamada. En SO en inglés hay un montón de ejemplos sobre esto.